# xts to.quarterly giving incorrect results for monthly

Tags: r, time-series, frequency, xts, zoo

When I do the following monthly -> quarterly conversion

```
xts.testm <- xts(rnorm(440*12, mean=0, sd=10), order.by=timeBasedSeq(155001/1989))
xts.testq<-to.quarterly(xts.testm, OHLC = FALSE)
tail(xts.testm)
tail(xts.testq)
```

I get the following output that shows the original monthly and new quarterly output:

```
               [,1]
Jul 1989  4.4441175
Aug 1989 -0.2839412
Sep 1989 -3.3491154
Oct 1989 -1.9351425
Nov 1989  7.5427961
Dec 1989 -4.5846861
> tail(xts.testq)
             [,1]
1988 Q4 -1.537608
1989 Q1 -7.190733
1989 Q2  9.430785
1989 Q3  4.444117
1989 Q4 -1.935143
1989 Q4 -4.584686
```

Notice the duplicate last quarter and the incorrect values. `to.quarterly` is supposed to grab the last value. It isn't. `Sep 1989 -3.349` should be `1989Q3 -4.44` and `Dec 1989 -4.58` should be `1989Q4 -4.58`. Somehow there's two `1989Q4` values. Somehow October and July's values are being grabbed instead of September and Decembers values.

What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the version of xts on CRAN that has been fixed in the [development version](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts).

The problem is that your `xts.testm` object is using your local timezone even though the index is a `yearmon` class (which doesn't have a timezone). This is fixed in the deveopment version by ensuring that all index classes that do not have a timezone (e.g. Date, yearmon, yearqtr, chron) have a `TZ` of `"UTC"`.

Using xts from CRAN:

```
R> set.seed(21)
R> xts.testm <- xts(rnorm(440*12, sd=10), order.by=timeBasedSeq(155001/1989))
R> str(xts.testm)  # "TZ: " implies local timezone
An ‘xts’ object on Jan 1550/Dec 1989 containing:
  Data: num [1:5280, 1] 7.93 5.22 17.46 -12.71 21.97 ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [yearmon] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
R> xts.testq <- to.quarterly(xts.testm, OHLC = FALSE)
R> tail(xts.testq)
              [,1]
1988 Q4 -17.874026
1989 Q1   3.346780
1989 Q2  18.418469
1989 Q3   9.461461
1989 Q4 -16.074923
1989 Q4  -3.615878
```

Using current development version of xts:

```
R> set.seed(21)
R> xts.testm <- xts(rnorm(440*12, sd=10), order.by=timeBasedSeq(155001/1989))
R> str(xts.testm)  # note "TZ: UTC"
An ‘xts’ object on Jan 1550/Dec 1989 containing:
  Data: num [1:5280, 1] 7.93 5.22 17.46 -12.71 21.97 ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [yearmon] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
R> xts.testq <- to.quarterly(xts.testm, OHLC = FALSE)
R> tail(xts.testq)
              [,1]
1988 Q3   4.936151
1988 Q4   5.404136
1989 Q1  -3.331241
1989 Q2 -23.621581
1989 Q3   2.687675
1989 Q4  -3.615878
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I'm still new to R so please forgive my ignorance but how would I go about using the development version that you've kindly linked? Do I need this "R-devel" that I've read about?

Comment: @Knixd: it's just the development version of xts, not the development version of R.

Comment: Wonderful. I'll look into using the development version of xts.Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Try with a reproducible example using `set.seed()`.

```
set.seed(10)
xts.testm <- xts(rnorm(440*12, mean=0, sd=10), order.by=timeBasedSeq(155001/1989))
xts.testq<-to.quarterly(xts.testm, OHLC = FALSE)
tail(xts.testm,12)
tail(xts.testq,8)
```

Do you have this output?

```
tail(xts.testm,12)
               [,1]
dic 1988 -16.984259
gen 1989 -13.103928
feb 1989  -3.515761
mar 1989  23.712606
apr 1989   6.635250
mag 1989  13.826195
giu 1989   1.771894
lug 1989 -11.096838
ago 1989  14.664982
set 1989  12.516992
ott 1989  11.572212
nov 1989 -18.763949
> tail(xts.testq,8)
               [,1]
1988 Q1   4.2217167
1988 Q2   0.4267038
1988 Q3  25.3994248
1988 Q4 -16.9842591
1989 Q1  23.7126065
1989 Q2   1.7718940
1989 Q3  12.5169922
1989 Q4 -18.7639487
```